# Dar diferentes permisos a distintos usuarios sobre un mismo modelo/vista Odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo

Tengo un modulo personalizado llamado historial clínico, con los campos diagnostico y tratamientos. Lo que quiero es que con un usuario 'Enfermero'  pueda modificar el campo tratamientos y solo poder leer el de diagnósticos. Y con el usuario 'Medico' modificar el campo diagnostico y leer/modificar el campo tratamientos. Como se darían estos permisos sobre las vistas o donde? Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para ello tendrías que crear tus grupos en un archivo security,y despues crear tus reglas de acceso en el archivo ir.model.access.csv en donde le permites a cada grupo leer, escribir, borrar, actualizar...